# in der Zeit vs zu Zeiten/Erstarrter Dativ Plural

Tags: grammar-identification

I am trying to understand the usage of zu Zeiten. Pons tells me this is just [in der Zeit](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsche-rechtschreibung/zu+Zeiten). In Duden, the following is written for Herkunft:

> Bestandteil erstarrter Dativ Plural von Zeit

I don't quite get what the above is saying. Translate tells me:

> Component of solidified dative plural of time

Solidified dative plural... what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some grammar features that aren't used any more in contemporary language. However, they survived in fixed phrases as *zu Zeiten*. That's what the Duden describes as *erstarrt*. The expression is frozen in time. It doesn't change any more nor are there going to be any new of that kind.

Comment: I still don’t get it. What is frozen in time here? The phrase is frozen, yes, like any other phrase. But the plural dative of “Zeit” ist still in use and is part of contemporary phrases as well.

Comment: A more common example is "zu Hause". The dative of "Haus" in German is "Haus", but the past adding an "-e" was common in the past. A similar phrase in English is "to thine own self be true." This is a quote from Shakespeare and his day "thine" was used all the time. It's obsolete now, of course, but it's still used in the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after my comment to the other answer by Janka, I found some information, that makes more sense to me:
The Herkunftshinweis you mentioned is not for “zu Zeiten”, but for “zuzeiten” (which is developed from the phrase “zu Zeiten”) and it says “**2.** Bestandteil…”. This means, “The second part of ‘zuzeiten’ is plural dative of ‘Zeit’ and is now frozen inside the new word ‘zuzeiten’”

Comment: Please, if you down-vote an answer, leave short comment, that tells everybody (at least me), _why_ you did.

Comment: I wonder as well.